# Ubuntu 14.0.4 freezing

Tags: password

I've just installed 14.0.4 and it freezes if left for any amount of time (more than a few minutes)

The mouse moves, but any input on the keyboard isn't shown on screen (password lock screen)

The lights on the keyboard work and I can toggle the caps lock/ number lock etc.

Many thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem some time ago. In the end, it was the keyboard cable that was malfunctioning.